# Android webview form submit in evaluateJavascript not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview

This is happening recently (July 2020) on Android WebView.

Submitting a form using evaluateJavascript is not working. The page does "submit" but the POST values are not received by the server.

Was there a security change or other update to Android WebView that will prevent form submissions?

Any JavaScript form submit alternatives?

Simple HTML page with a single form, single input, and a submit button. Loaded into the webview from a URL.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="stwiosbtn.aspx" id="form1">
<input name="txtField1" type="text" id="txtField1" style="width:90%;" />
<input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" id="btnSave" style="width:90%;" />
</form>
```

The Java Code in Android Studio

```
String jScript = "document.forms[0].submit();";
mywebview.evaluateJavascript(jScript, null);
```

The form in the webview does submit, there is an onPageLoad triggered after the function is called. But the values are not posted. Nothing is sent from the input value. Only when clicking the submit button.

Interestingly, this works, but sending a click to a button does not meet the requirements I am trying to meet.

```
String jScript = "var mysubmitbutton = document.getElementsByName('btnSave'); mysubmitbutton[0].click();";
mywebview.evaluateJavascript(jScript, null);
```

This is an established app. The forms[0].submit(); was working only a few weeks ago. Also the iOS version with the WKWebView has the same JavaScript and works fine. This is only on Android.

Also tried the following and none of these worked either;

```
String jScript = "function doTheThing(){ " +
    "var sendform = document.forms[0]; " +
    "sendform.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', { cancelable: true })) } " +
    "doTheThing();";

String jScript = "document.getElementById('form1').submit()";

String jScript = "document.getElementById(\"form1\").submit();";
```

Comment: You should write that JavaScript in a separate file and load it up into a string so that you get proper tooling for the language

Answer (score 0):

This is a .Net host issue, not Android after all.

Posting our findings to help other developers.

The page being used is a .Net site.
Instead of managing the form response in the page_load, the website developer used an _onclick event for the submit button. Using just document.forms[0].submit(); does not tigger the server side click event for the button, even if that button is a submit button.

Something to be aware of.

This used to work with the same Android and .Net code. It is possible the .Net framework made a change or other library was changed in such a way that the submit() no longer triggers server side _onclick of a submit button.

We did also try forms[0].requestSumit();
This also did not work